# Which methodology ensures good user exprience?

Tags: design, users, tools, experience

There's discovery, design, implement and refine where designers have their own set of tools to achieve the expected output and make clients happy.I came across [this blog](https://inkoniq.com/blog/killer-designer-tools-to-enhance-the-scope-of-user-experience/) today, there are a few good tools mentioned which will come handy at each step of user experience, but I am not convinced.

**What do you guys prefer?** Can you state your reasons or examples of why opting for a particular tool

Comment: I think the question you should ask is which methodology ensures best user experience, not which tools.

Comment: Sure... thanks for correcting me, I am new here. I will edit the question  :)

Answer (score 1):

These guys did a thorough research and came up with the **Design Tools Survey**

You should find all your answers here : http://tools.subtraction.com/